# github asking for verification code on every selenium-webdriver test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, github, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to login on Github using selenium-webdriver 
whenever I am trying to run my python script GitHub ask me for the verification code to verify my device which leads to unsuccessful login because it is not possible for me to check my mail every time and verify my verification code every time. is there is something wrong with my code?
here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from importlib import reload
import time
import sys

reload(sys)


# Firefox used
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# base url
driver.get("http://github.com/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_id("login_field")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

# password and username need to go into these values
username.send_keys("username")
time.sleep(1)
password.send_keys("password")
time.sleep(1)

login_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sign in']")
time.sleep(1)
login_form.click()
time.sleep(1)

# These are some of the most popular users on github
prepend = ["jashkenas", "ruanyf", "substack", "kennethreitz", "jlord", "daimajia", "mdo", "schacon", "mattt",
           "sindresorhus", "defunkt", "douglascrockford", "mbostock", "jeresig",
           "mojombo", "addyosmani", "paulirish", "vczh", "romannurik", "tenderlove", "chriscoyier", "johnpapa",
           "josevalim",
           "charliesome", "CoderMJLee", "ry", "antirez", "muan", "isaacs", "angusshire",
           "hadley", "hakimel", "yyx990803", "fat", "fabpot", "ibireme", "tekkub",
           "BYVoid", "laruence", "onevcat", "tpope", "mrdoob", "LeaVerou", "chrisbanes", "wycats", "lifesinger",
           "cloudwu", "mitsuhiko", "michaelliao", "ryanb", "clowwindy", "JacksonTian", "yinwang0", "Trinea",
           "pjhyett", "dhh", "gaearon"]

for user in prepend:
    for t in range(1, 100):

        string = "https://github.com/{}/followers?page={}".format(user, t)
        driver.get(string)
        time.sleep(1)

        # make sure to pick the correct directory to save the files to
        # follow_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
        follow_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Follow this person']")

        # Once page is loaded this clicks all buttons for follow
        try:
            for i in follow_button:
                i.submit()
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(1)

driver.close()
```

Comment: `github` doesn't want you to crawl their site.  What are you trying to accomplish anyway?

Comment: GitHub provides an API for a reason.. don't scrape

Comment: but when I running my script yesterday it works well. but today it asks for verification-code

Comment: Yep.  Github let you do it a couple of times, and then they blocked you.  This is normal when you violate the TOS for major websites.